# wordpress-menus like multi-level menus

Tags: jquery, wordpress

You must know WP 3's multi-level menu configuration feature on the dashboard.

I was wondering how WordPress is doing that. Yes, I know they are using jQuery UI. But still, how? Is there any documentation?

Or is there any plugin or anything that shall help me?

Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: Re your update: Okay, but which aspect are you asking about? The programming one? The visual one? The GUI? The drag & drop functionality? How to save the structure?

Comment: The tree ing functionality (drag and drop!) and how to save it. I wish to do only level-one sub-menus for my plugin.

Answer (score 18):

Nestable

Drag & drop hierarchical list with mouse and touch compatibility (jQuery plugin)

http://dbushell.github.com/Nestable/

Comment: if you need also Add/Edit/Delete features, check my fork of that plugin:  https://github.com/ShinDarth/Nestable

Answer (score 11):

I used Nestable jQuery plugin to accomplish it, but I forked it to add some extra features (Add/Delete/Edit actions and Slug property):

https://github.com/FrancescoBorzi/Nestable

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was looking exactly for that ;)

Comment: @ShinDarth Would be even cooler if you could initialise it with a previously saved serialised output string.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery UI Sortable docs and samples: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/